# "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until" on a Label

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke

I've read several questions/answers related to this problem but couldn't find a solution applicable to problem.

I have a form (`MainForm`) and a button (`Upload`) on it. When I click on the button  (after selecting a file from a ComboBox to be uploaded to the server), it opens another form (`UploadBackupForm`) and uploads a file to the server. The upload process is controlled in `UploadBackupForm` and the form looks like this:

[image: Screenshot from the app]

This works as long as upload is done once, I mean, the `UploadBackupForm` is called one time. The second time I click on the Upload button, `UploadBackupForm` opens and (after uploading some data) it throws an error saying:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'

at this specific line(s):

```
DurationLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    DurationLabel.Text = Count2Duration(count);
});
```

This has puzzled me because it works when it's done once, and doesn't work at the second time. I have basic knowdledge in C#, so I don't know what's causing this and how to solve it.

`MainForm`:

```
private void Upload2ServerButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form UBF = new UploadBackupForm();
    UBF.ShowDialog();
}
```

`UploadBackupForm`:

```
public partial class UploadBackupForm : Form
{
    public UploadBackupForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public static int count = 0;

    private void UploadBackup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Interval = 1000;

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(delegate {
            count++;
            // didn't do any good (this.IsHandleCreated or DurationLabel.IsHandleCreated)
            // if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
            // {
                // this.CreateControl();
            // }
            DurationLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                DurationLabel.Text = Count2Duration(count);
            });
        });

        // upload the archive to the server
        new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
        {
            FTP.Item[] items = FTP.ListDirectoryDetails(DataIO.FTP.Server, DataIO.FTP.Username, DataIO.FTP.Password, DataIO.FTP.UploadDir);

            // here, I upload the file to the server and update the progress bar and the uploaded / total labels
```

Comment: Make both `timer` and `count` non static (remove `static` keyword). Also stop that timer when form is closed.

Comment: @Evk Removing `static` worked. Thank you. Timer is stopped when the upload is done (before the form is closed). I really should read more about C# :) Also is this a simple mistake (because it seems like one) or is there more to it? If there is, you can post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I consider it simple, someone else might not, that's subjective :)

Comment: Haha, true. Anyway, BartoszKP elaborated on the problem. It'll do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `timer` variable is static it remains even after the form is closed. It contains a reference to a delegate which holds a reference to the form so the previous instances are kept alive through the lifetime of your application. Also, the single `timer` posts callbacks to all previous instances along with the current one.

As correctly noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606928/invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-on-a-label/49607136#comment86220525_49606928) by [Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk), make the `timer` and `count` non-static so they are dedicated to each instance of the form.